# Unable to change the color of nodes using neuralnetwork package

Tags: tikz-styles, neuralnetwork

[image]

I am trying to change nodes' border color and body color using the neural-network package. I am finding difficulties in the same. I want to change the arrow colors to black too.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{neuralnetwork}
\begin{document}
%\tikzset{inputlayer/.style={line width=1pt, fill=black}}    
    \makeatletter
 {\nn@nodecaption{\nn@layerindex}{}} {\nn@nodecaption{\nn@layerindex}{\nn@nodeindex}}{}{}
% define the nodeindex to be zero initially
\newcommand\nn@nodeindex{0}
\newcommand{\nodetextx}[2]{
  \ifnum \nn@nodeindex=0
     $\mathbf{c_1}$
  \else
     $i_{#2}$
  \fi
}
\newcommand{\nodetextz}[2]{$o_1$}
\newcommand{\nodetexth}[2]{
  \ifnum \nn@nodeindex=0
    $\mathbf{c_2}$
  \else
    $h_{1, #2}$
  \fi
}
\newcommand{\nodetexthto}[2]{
  \ifnum \nn@nodeindex=0
    $\mathbf{c_2}$
  \else
    $h_{2, #2}$
  \fi
}
\newcommand{\nodetexthtoo}[2]{
  \ifnum \nn@nodeindex=0
    $\mathbf{c_2}$
  \else
    $h_{3, #2}$
  \fi
}
\resizebox{1.5\columnwidth}{!}{%
\begin{neuralnetwork}[height=1.5 ,maintitleheight=1cm,layertitleheight=4cm,]
  \inputlayer[count=8, bias=false, title={Input}, text=\nodetextx]
  \hiddenlayer[count=5, bias=false, title={Dense1}, text=\nodetexth]
  \linklayers
  \hiddenlayer[count=5, bias=false, title={Dense2}, text=\nodetexthto]
  \linklayers
   \hiddenlayer[count=5, bias=false, title={Dense3}, text=\nodetexthtoo]
  \linklayers
  \outputlayer[count=3, title={Output}, text=\nodetextz] 
  \linklayers
\end{neuralnetwork}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link color is easy, there is an optional argument to `\linklayers` where you can specify several keys to be used for the links. One of them is `style`, which can contain the color (among other things). For example:

```
\linklayers[style=black]
```

For more information about the keys for links see the [Github page of the package](https://github.com/battlesnake/neural) at the end of the README file.

The color of the nodes is a bit more difficult, this is hardcoded in the package. For example, the `\hiddenlayer` command is defined as follows in the package:

```
\newcommand{\hiddenlayer}[1][] { \layer[bias=true,nodeclass={hidden neuron},#1] }
```

This means that a `\layer` command is called with the `nodeclass` key set to `hidden neuron` and any other arguments are added to this `\layer` command through `#1`, like the count, the title and the text. The nodeclass `hidden neuron` is defined as follows, with the hardcoded value for the color:

```
\tikzstyle{hidden neuron}=[neuron, fill=blue!40];
```

So, to change the color, a solution is to define a new layer command that uses a different `nodeclass` in which we set a different color, as follows:

```
\tikzstyle{hiddenorange}=[neuron, fill=orange];
\newcommand{\hiddenlayerorange}[1][] { \layer[bias=true,nodeclass={hiddenorange},#1] }
```

However, this means you need to create and use a new command and a new style for each color. To make it easier to use, the color parameter can be given as a key to the layer. Following the conventions that the `neuralnetwork` package has, the code for defining the key and storing the key value is:

```
\define@key{layer}{layercolor} {\def\nnlayercolor{#1}}
```

This means that the key `layercolor` given as argument to a `\layer` command will be stored in the macro `\nnlayercolor`. Now this macro can be used within the style:

```
\makeatletter
\define@key{layer}{layercolor} {\def\nnlayercolor{#1}}
\makeatother

\tikzstyle{hiddencl}=[neuron, fill=\nnlayercolor]
\newcommand{\hiddenlayercolor}[1][] { \layer[bias=true,nodeclass={hiddencl},#1] }
```

Note that `\define@key` contains an `@` symbol, therefore the command must be surrounded by `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`.

Full MWE (simplified from the code given in the question):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{neuralnetwork}
\newcommand{\nodetextx}[2]{$i_{#2}$}
\newcommand{\nodetextz}[2]{$o_#2$}
\newcommand{\nodetexth}[2]{$h_{#1,#2}$}
\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\define@key{layer}{layercolor} {\def\nnlayercolor{#1}}
\makeatother

\tikzstyle{hiddencl}=[neuron, fill=\nnlayercolor]
\newcommand{\hiddenlayercolor}[1][] { \layer[bias=true,nodeclass={hiddencl},#1] }

\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{neuralnetwork}[height=1.5,maintitleheight=1cm,layertitleheight=4cm,]
  \inputlayer[count=8, bias=false, title={Input}, text=\nodetextx]
  \hiddenlayercolor[layercolor=orange!60, count=5, bias=false, title={Dense1}, text=\nodetexth]
  \linklayers
  \hiddenlayercolor[layercolor=purple!40, count=5, bias=false, title={Dense2}, text=\nodetexth]
  \linklayers
   \hiddenlayer[count=5, bias=false, title={Dense3}, text=\nodetexth]
  \linklayers[style=black]
  \outputlayer[count=3, title={Output}, text=\nodetextz] 
  \linklayers
\end{neuralnetwork}}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Note that this code uses `\tikzstyle`, which is deprecated, but the package uses it so I decided to keep it for this answer.